# How can I use the volume buttons for skipping songs?

Tags: nexus-one, music

Is there a way to use the volume buttons to change songs on the Nexus One?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the lock-screen is enabled, Android disallows apps to interact with buttons in the way you ask. However, though it's not an app, but I believe CyanogenMod ROM allows for this. And if that's the case, there will be other ROMs out there that allow for the same.